# How to config local domain without `IPv6/MX` records with dnsmasq?

Tags: dnsmasq

I use the dnsmasq server to manage domain list inside our product.

And I config with the hosts like this. `--addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq.d/hosts/service`

`cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/hosts/service`

```
192.168.190.100 test.product.com
```

and In another part of the product I have to make a http request to this domain.

I looks like this, `cat http_get.py`:

```
import requests
import sys

URL = "http://test.product.com"
r = requests.get(url = URL, timeout=1)
data = r.json()
print data
```

when run with `time python http_get.py`,  it use almost 10s for dns request.

I have analyzed the dns request with tcpdump.

It shows that it make two type of DNS Request.

```
22:48:06.990049 IP l2.47857 > l2.domain: 18996+ A? test.product.com. (29)
22:48:06.990241 IP l2.47857 > l2.domain: 19787+ AAAA? test.product.com. (29)
...
22:48:11.994835 IP l2.47857 > l2.domain: 18996+ A? test.product.com. (29)
22:48:11.995081 IP l2.47857 > l2.domain: 19787+ AAAA? test.product.com. (29)
```

And the request of `AAAA`(IPv6) type is not what i need. It shows that it hanged almost 10s within 2 attempt.

How to config it in the `/etc/dnsmasq.d/hosts/service` file?

There is another type of request `MX` of `test.product.com` that I have observed from my product. And it hangs like the `AAAA`(IPv6) request.

Any suggestions is welcome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in virtual DNS server and configure records in `/etc/hosts`.

192.168.190.100 test.product.local

And also always do everything with standards in mind.
Do not use test.product.com and use TLDs specifically intended for local or test use (`.local` and `.test`).

Comment: Thanks for your TLD domain suggestion. And our product is deployed over multi-hosts, if I configure the /etc/hosts it must change the all hosts at the same time, we want to use the dns as an failover when we detect some service is outage.